# How to select attributes which are starts with range (A-Z) from database in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel-5

How to select attributes which are starts with range (A-Z) from database and store them in one variable to display alphabetically ordered in Laravel5.2?

This is my code, but I couldn't get my desired result.

```
for ($char = 'A';$char<= 'Z';$char++)
    {

        $viewAll = Product::where('p_name' , 'like',$char.'%')->get();

    } return view('inventory.index',['product'=>$viewAll]);
```

Comment: Why not just use `orderBy('p_name')`?

Comment: Thank You.Then how do I display those data in my view page lexicographically? Products name starts with A will show be shown separately while products name starts with B will show be shown separately and so on.

Comment: Has my answer solved your question?

Comment: Ya It helped me and I have to seek more help from this.https://github.com/laracasts/How-I-Organize-Tags-By-Letter Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend sorting the products in SQL then grouping the results by first letter using the [Collections `groupBy()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-groupby).

```
// Get all the products sorted by name
$viewAll = Product::orderBy('p_name')->get();

// Group them by letter
$viewAll = $viewAll->groupBy(function($product) {
    return substr($product['p_name'], 0, 1);
});

// resulting array will be 
// [
//      'a' => [{p_name: 'apple'}, ...],
//      'b' => [{p_name: 'banana'}, ...],
//      'c' => [...]
// ]
```